# Jenkins will look for available node

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in jenkins that run batch file on few nodes. I did it using node parameter. I also added condition that it will run few times. This job is running in parallel but when one host is stack I would like it to continue running this job on other nodes. This is not working. Jenkins is going to the first parameter in the node and trying to run on it and if it is stuck it will not continue to other node. I would like jenkins to look for available node. I tried using multi job plunging and it also didnt work. Also tried working with label but it is not running in parallel....any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add labels to your node , if you have 4 slaves on ly 2 are windows both will have the label **windows** , than in your job use the [Restrict where this project can be run](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin)  , add the label value - **windows**

if you need to run the same job in parallel you can create  [a matrix job](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) , the same flow will run on several slaves.

Comment: I tried that and it is not running in parallel. I need all the nodes to run together. With label, jenkins will run first node then the next and etc....any other ideas ?

Comment: did you mark the **Execute concurrent builds if necessary** in you job ?

Comment: Yes, but since it is one job that runs, jenkins will start running it on available node and then only when batch file will end he will check the condition and will run it again.... not together

Comment: you want to run the same job in parallel , or run the script on several nodes ?

Comment: I want to run the same job in parallel

Comment: so maybe you need to run using a matrix job , create one job that trigger the same flow on several slaves.

Comment: Ok, can you send me some example or explanation how to configure it ?